# How to speed up join query in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 to to join two tables together. But for some reason the process is taking way too long. Both tables have index. The tables have around 280 rows and 5-6 columns. But they do have a geometry column with complex boundaries of countries.

This is how the query looks like:

```
sqlstr = """CREATE TABLE {new_table_name} AS (
              SELECT {geom_table_columns}, {added_columns} 
              FROM {geom_table} 
              INNER JOIN {temp_table} ON 
                (g.{id} = {temp_table}.{id})
            );
         """.format(** {
            'new_table_name': new_table,
            'geom_table': geom_table_name,
            'geom_table_columns': geom_table_columns,
            'temp_table': table_name_temp,
            'id': geom_table_id,
            'added_columns': added_columns
        })
```

Is there any way to make this inner join query faster?

Comment: Please edit the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. Are `shared_buffers`, `work_mem` and `effective_cache_size` configured correctly?

Comment: JFYI: `foo(**{'bar': baz})` is equivalent to `foo(bar=baz)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe does EXPLAIN works with CREATE?

Comment: @user1919: It works with the `select` which is the key.

Comment: Also, is g an alias for geom_table? I assume so, but you are missing the alias in your query, should be FROM {geom_table} g or change g.{id} to {geom_table}.{id}

Comment: Also you should be using psycopg2 parameter passing instead of format, because you can potentially do sql injection with this.